# Getting ylim from loop of pyplot.plot actions - only the last one in loop registers and everything else is 0, 1

Tags: python, matplotlib

**Objective**
I want to use a loop to generate different subplots and, while in each iteration, I want to pass out the ylims for each subplot to use in another function.

**Problem**
When I do this, I only get the ylims of the last subplot. All of the others are 0.0, 1.0. I am overwriting the variable: `limits = plt.ylim()` with each iteration, and I realize this, however I thought printing it at that iteration would show the variable and containing it in a dictionary of y limits would be helpful to see what is going in. In both the print instance and the update dictionary instance, the values come out as 0.0, 1.0 even thought that is clearly not the case. It seems like the answer is going to be obvious, however I can't figure out how to preserve those values through a loop.

**Example Code**

```
    aa={'x':[1,2], 'y':[3,4]}
    bb={'x':[10,20], 'y':[30,40]}
    cc={'x':[15,23], 'y':[35,43]}
    plot_names=['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
    plot_dict={'aa':aa, 'bb':bb, 'cc':cc}
    fig, axlist = plt.subplots(len(plot_dict))
    lim_dict={}
    for jj, ax in enumerate(axlist.flat):
        print('jj = '+ plot_names[jj])
        print('ax = '+str(ax))
        ax.plot(plot_dict[plot_names[jj]]['x'], plot_dict[plot_names[jj]]['y'])
        limits=plt.ylim()
        lim_dict |= {plot_names[jj]:limits}
        print(plot_names[jj] + str(limits))
        
    print(lim_dict)
```

**Output**

```
jj = aa
ax = AxesSubplot(0.125,0.657941;0.775x0.222059)
aa(0.0, 1.0)
jj = bb
ax = AxesSubplot(0.125,0.391471;0.775x0.222059)
bb(0.0, 1.0)
jj = cc
ax = AxesSubplot(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.222059)
cc(34.6, 43.4)
{'aa': (0.0, 1.0), 'bb': (0.0, 1.0), 'cc': (34.6, 43.4)}
```

**Summary**
You can see that in the output, both the first two printed instances of `limits` and the printed dictionary outside the loop `lim_dict` show values of 0.0 and 1.0. *Why*?

**System:**
Python3 (version 3.9.1 64 bit)
ipynb file in VSCode
Windows 10

Comment: I am not sure I got it correctly. What about ```limits=ax.get_ylim()``` instead of ```limits=plt.ylim()```?

Comment: fdireto - That was the essence of my first try. I don't know if `pyplot.get_ylim` has been deprecated or something, but basically it just returns `matplotlib has no attribute "get_ylim"`.The documentation for `ylim` says it can be used for both "getting" and "setting" y-limits, so it seems to me that `get_ylim` has become redundant. Furthermore, `pyplot.ylim` works in the last instance of the loop, so I think I have set up the loop incorrectly or I don't understand variable storage in axes

Comment: You cannot use `plt.get_ylim()` - this function returns the y-axis limits of the specified axis object. So, `ax.get_ylim()` works, `plt.gca().get_ylim()` works (because it determines the last used axis object), but not `plt.get_ylim()`. I suggest you read [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-usage-py) explaining differences between the object-oriented interface when you use axes objects and the pyplot interface.

Comment: Excellent point, Mr. T, however it didn't solve the problem. Whereas changing the call for `limits` to `plt.gca().get_ylim()` works (does not throw an error, I still have the trouble with all values but the last value being (0.1, 1.0) for the y-limits. I think the discussion between `ylim` vs. `get_ylim` has derailed the conversation from the main problem and it seems like both calls to populate the `limits` container work equally poorly under my loop structure.

Comment: I get ```{'aa': (2.95, 4.05), 'bb': (29.5, 40.5), 'cc': (34.6, 43.4)}```, when I run. Is this the correct output?

Comment: Inside the loop, do ```print(ax)``` and ```print(plt.gca())```. The plt.gca() refers always to the bottom subplot. Because it is only updated in the last iteration, its limits are 0 and 1 until then.

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't realize that the `plt.gca()` only referred to the last subplot - I thought it would actually **"get current axis"** when it was inside the loop. And i also felt that the answer was right under my nose, I just couldn't find it. Thank you.

Comment: Great to know it works! I thought that too... And just to be clear about my wording in the previous comment, the ```plt.gca()``` gives that result in this code. The "why" and if it is that way in other situations are beyond my knowledge, I'm afraid.